# How to "join" partially hidden numbers by * (Python)

Tags: python, sorting, tuples, compare

I'll keep it as simple as possible.

Let's say you have a tuple list, for example:

```
[('0000************', 'b'), ('****1234********', 'a'),
('****1111****3333', 'b')]
```

How could I join the numbers of the same type. Basically turn the example above into something like this:

```
[('****1234********', 'a'), ('00001111****3333', 'b')]
```

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 3):

One possible solution: create a dictionary of the first values indexed by the second and when a duplicate second value is found, merge the first values (in this case I've given precedence to the first ones). Then convert that dictionary back to a list of tuples:

```
tups = [('0000************', 'b'), ('****1234********', 'a'), ('****1111****3333', 'b')]

def merge_nums(n, m):
    return ''.join(a if a != '*' else b for a, b in zip(n, m))

out = {}
for (v, k) in tups:
    out[k] = merge_nums(out[k], v) if k in out else v
res = [(v, k) for k, v in out.items()]

print(res)
```

Output:

```
[('****1234********', 'a'), ('00001111****3333', 'b')]
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure how efficient it is, but this works.
Note that you're potentially overwriting numbers if there are values at the same index per type.

```
x = [('0000************', 'b'), ('****1234********', 'a'), ('****1111****3333', 'b')]

types = {}

for y in x:
    if y[1] in types:
        i = 0
        for z in y[0]:
            if z != '*':
                types[y[1]] = types[y[1]][0:i] + z + types[y[1]][i:-1]
            i += 1
    else:
        types[y[1]] = y[0]

print(types)
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you will only need to match pairs of strings one of which has a digit and the other doesn't, you can loop through all possible pairs of tuples, extract the tuples when they match, then combine their strings. I expanded your example list of tuples to show the code is generalizable.

```
import itertools

list_of_tuples = [('0000************', 'b'), ('****1234********', 'a'),
('****1111****3333', 'b'), ('0000************', 'a')]

# combine two strings of the same length by digit
def combine_strings(str1, str2):
    new_string = ''
    for index, char in enumerate(str1):
        if char.isdigit():
            new_string += char
        else:
            new_string += str2[index]
    return new_string

# return all pairs of tuples that have a matching second element
def get_pairs(list_of_tuples):
    all_matches = []
    for pair in itertools.combinations(list_of_tuples, 2):
        if pair[0][1] == pair[1][1]:
            all_matches.append(pair)
    return all_matches

def combine_tuples(tuple1, tuple2):
    return (combine_strings(tuple1[0], tuple2[0]), tuple1[1])

all_matched_tuples = get_pairs(list_of_tuples) 
print(all_matched_tuples)
list_matched_tuples = []
for pair in all_matched_tuples:
    list_matched_tuples.append(combine_tuples(pair[0], pair[1]))
```

Output:

```
> list_matched_tuples
[('00001111****3333', 'b'), ('00001234********', 'a')]
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use `itertools.groupby`:

```
from itertools import groupby as gb
d = [('0000************', 'b'), ('****1234********', 'a'), ('****1111****3333', 'b')]
def merge(vals):
  return ['*' if not (x:=list(filter(str.isdigit, j))) else x[0] for j in zip(*vals)]

r = [(''.join(merge([j for j, _ in b])), a) for a, b in gb(sorted(d, key=lambda x:x[-1]), key=lambda x:x[-1])]
```

Output:

```
[('****1234********', 'a'), ('00001111****3333', 'b')]
```